# How to pass terraform variables in GitHub workflow

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow to deploy on AWs using terraform and I am struggling to pass terraform variables.

The following step fails because can’t find the variables define in variables.tf

```
- name: Terraform Plan
    id: plan
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
    env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.ECR_REPO }}
        django_secret_key: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}
        admin: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN }}
        admin_email: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_EMAIL }}
        admin_password: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD }}
        db_username: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_USERNAME }}
        db_password: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_PASSWORD }}
    run: |
     export ecr_image_api=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:dev
     terraform init
     terraform workspace select staging || terraform workspace new staging
     terraform plan -no-color -input=false
    continue-on-error: true
```

In gitlab ci I just defined the tf_variables as CI variables so I did the same in GitHub but the ci fails with this error message

```
Run export TF_VAR_ecr_image_api=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:dev
  export TF_VAR_ecr_image_api=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:dev
  terraform init
  terraform workspace select staging || terraform workspace new staging
  terraform plan -no-color -input=false
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    TERRAFORM_CLI_PATH: /home/runner/work/_temp/0bf615bc-6784-4171-a424-de5f1040eae8
    ECR_REGISTRY: ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    ECR_REPOSITORY: ***
    TF_VAR_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ***
    TF_VAR_ADMIN: ***
    TF_VAR_ADMIN_EMAIL: ***
    TF_VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ***
    TF_VAR_DB_USERNAME: ***
    TF_VAR_DB_PASSWORD: ***
/home/runner/work/_temp/0bf615bc-6784-4171-a424-de5f1040eae8/terraform-bin init

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/template from the dependency lock file
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v4.15.1
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/template v2.2.0

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.



/home/runner/work/_temp/0bf615bc-6784-4171-a424-de5f1040eae8/terraform-bin workspace select staging
Switched to workspace "staging".



/home/runner/work/_temp/0bf615bc-6784-4171-a424-de5f1040eae8/terraform-bin plan -no-color -input=false
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Error: No value for required variable

  on variables.tf line 11:
  11: variable "db_***" {

The root module input variable "db_***" is not set, and has no default
value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for
this variable.

Error: No value for required variable

  on variables.tf line 14:
  14: variable "db_***" {

The root module input variable "db_***" is not set, and has no default
value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for
this variable.

Error: No value for required variable

  on variables.tf line 31:
  31: variable "django_***_key" {

The root module input variable "django_***_key" is not set, and has no
default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a
value for this variable.

Error: No value for required variable

  on variables.tf line 34:
  34: variable "***" {

The root module input variable "***" is not set, and has no default value.
Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for this
variable.

Error: No value for required variable

  on variables.tf line 37:
  37: variable "***_email" {

The root module input variable "***_email" is not set, and has no default
value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for
this variable.

Error: No value for required variable

  on variables.tf line 40:
  40: variable "***_***" {

The root module input variable "***_***" is not set, and has no
default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a
value for this variable.



Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like that ?

```
- name: Terraform Plan
    id: plan
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
    env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.ECR_REPO }}
        django_secret_key: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}
        admin: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN }}
        admin_email: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_EMAIL }}
        admin_password: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD }}
        db_username: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_USERNAME }}
        db_password: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_PASSWORD }}
    run: |
     export ecr_image_api=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:dev
     terraform init
     terraform workspace select staging || terraform workspace new staging
     terraform plan -var="db_username=${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_USERNAME }}" -var="db_password==${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_PASSWORD }}" -var="admin_email=${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_EMAIL }}" -var="admin_password=${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD }}" -var="admin=${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN }}" -var="django_secret_key=${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}" -var="ECR_REGISTRY=${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}" -var="ECR_REPOSITORY=${{ secrets.ECR_REPO }}" -no-color -input=false
    continue-on-error: true
```

Comment: yeah. the log was infact saying to use the -var option but in gitlab CI I did not used it.. I just stored those variables as env variables with 'TF_VAR' prefix.

Answer (score 3):

Attaching a code snippet below. Using `TF_VAR` prefix will work. In the below snippet `env_account_ids` will be sent to the terraform plan below it.

```
 - name: Terraform Plan
    env:
      TF_VAR_env_account_ids: "[ XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ ]"
    run: terraform plan -out=plan
```

Answer (score 1):

its more useful and better to use them like that:

```
    env:
        TF_VAR_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}
        TF_VAR_ADMIN: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN }}
        TF_VAR_ADMIN_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_EMAIL }}
        TF_VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD }}
        TF_VAR_DB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_USERNAME }}
        TF_VAR_DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TF_VAR_DB_PASSWORD }}
```

It works on Github actions and it works in all cicd's because thats simple env variables for terraform. You can even define them locally